# Using Class Properties to return ODBC calls to another class

Tags: vb.net, properties

I have this class - CompLoc it returns two fields from a ODBC call.
I want to call the class like this.

```
dim myCompLoc as New CompLoc(company,location)
newCompany = mycompLoc.Company
newLocation = mycompLoc.Location
```

my Class.

```
 Private _company As String
Public Property Company() As String
    Get
        Return _company
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _company = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _location As String
Public Property Location() As String
    Get
        Return _location
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _location = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal loc As String, ByVal comp As String)
    'select company,location from mysqlTable Where location = loc and company = comp'
    _company = 'field from ODBC'
    _location = 'field from ODBC'
End Sub
```

I need to pass to the ODBC company and location, to return company and location (I know...not always in our hands). I have this class that I want to populate from the ODBC call.

```
corp.EmpId = currentRecord(0).ToString
corp.FirstName = currentRecord(1).ToString
corp.LastName = currentRecord(2).ToString
corp.BasePay = Decimal.Parse(currentRecord(3).ToString)
corp.corpCompany = currentRecord(4).ToString
corp.corpLocation = currentRecord(5).ToString
```

I need to add to the end of this class ---

```
corp.newCompany = myCompLoc.Company
corp.newLocation = myCompLoc.Location
```

Can I have some quidance to build my myCompLoc class properly so that I can call it from corp and receive both properties with values. I can pass this around as an array or other method, but i want to do it a better way.

Comment: what happens when you do what you want?  an error? is `myCompLoc` accessible from whereever that code is?

Comment: Yes, its accessible. I have no errors. I can return them seperately, i want to ask for myCompLoc, and receive both values typed inside. (sorry, if I am not asking correctly.)

Comment: what if `corp` had a property `thisCompany As CompLoc` and you just set it: `corp.thisCompany = myCompLoc`

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Can I pass two args to the constructor for the odbc calls? I think so.

Comment: i have no idea what these ODBC calls are or how their ctors are written.  are talking about UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE type procedures?

Comment: ODBC call is a select statement. it would return two fields, the newcompany and newlocation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55867/discussion-between-levi-and-plutonix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this. corpSQL inherits company and location from a properties class
corp inherits from corpMySql

```
Dim corporation as New Corporation
Dim corp As New corpMySql

 Dim newcorp = corp.Getcorp(corp.Company, corp.Location)
 corporation.Company = newcorp.NewCompany
 corporation.Plant = newcorp.NewLocation
```

I hope this makes sense. I was able to do what I set out to acheive, but I think another way is more fluid. Maybe using inheritence?